# React state from props that doesn't update (even doing destructuring and using different keys)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-props, react-state, react-refresh

Sorry for the long question in advance but I have been struggling with this for some time

To give some context of what I am trying to accomplish I am loading this table when my app loads

[image]

And when I click the button inside red square will bring the user to edit mode

[image]

In edit mode user should be able to for example toggle the `High School Core` (inside green square) checkbox and then discard the change by clicking `Discard Changes` button (inside blue square)

[image]

The thing is that it's not working, this checkbox should not be enabled because that `Discard Changes` button is only setting the `editMode` state to false and by doing that the table should be created by mapping other object: `const whichCourse = editMode ? modifiedValues : originalValues`

The original data from which `originalValues` and `modifiedValues` are created is passed to the `<Table />` component as a prop (that's a requirement for this app) from `App.tsx`

```tsx
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
import { Container } from "@mui/material";

import Table from "./Table";

const ID1 = uuidv4();
const ID2 = uuidv4();
const ID3 = uuidv4();

export const typedData = {
  bundles: [
    {
      id: ID1,
      name: "High School Core",
    },
    {
      id: ID2,
      name: "Middle School Core",
    },
    {
      id: ID3,
      name: "Elementary School Core",
    },
  ],
  schools: [
    {
      id: uuidv4(),
      name: "First School",
      licensedproducts: [ID1, ID2],
    },
    {
      id: uuidv4(),
      name: "Second School",
      licensedproducts: [ID2, ID3],
    },
  ],
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Table propsData={typedData} />
    </Container>
  );
}
```

File `Table.tsx` contains the following to render the UI and handle all logic

```tsx
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import CheckIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Check";
import { Box, Grid, Button, Checkbox } from "@mui/material";

import { typedData } from "./App";

const tableStyles = {
  display: "block",
  overflowX: "auto",
  paddingTop: "36px",
  whiteSpace: "nowrap",
  fontFamily: "Helvetica Neue",
  "& table": {
    width: "100%",
    textAlign: "center",
    borderCollapse: "collapse",
  },
  "& th, td": {
    px: "17px",
    color: "#1E1E24",
    fontSize: "14px",
    fontWeight: "400",
    lineHeight: "40px",
  },
  "& th": {
    borderBottom: "2px solid #00006D",
  },
  "& td": {
    borderBottom: "1px solid #dddddd",
  },
  "& th:nth-of-type(1), td:nth-of-type(1), th:nth-of-type(2), td:nth-of-type(2)": {
    textAlign: "left",
  },
};

export default function Table({ propsData }: { propsData: typeof typedData }) {
  const [editMode, setEditMode] = useState(false);

  const [originalValues, setOriginalValues] = useState({ ...propsData });
  const [modifiedValues, setModifiedValues] = useState({ ...propsData });

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("running useEffect");
    setOriginalValues({ ...propsData });
    setModifiedValues({ ...propsData });
  }, [propsData]);

  const whichCourse = editMode ? modifiedValues : originalValues;
  const keyComplement = editMode ? "yes" : "not";

  const toggleEdit = () => {
    setEditMode((current) => !current);
  };

  const saveButton = () => {
    setOriginalValues(modifiedValues);
  };

  return (
    <Box sx={{ textAlign: "center", pt: "10px" }}>
      <Grid container spacing={2}>
        <Grid item xs>
          <Button variant="contained" onClick={toggleEdit}>
            {editMode ? "Discard changes" : `Edit Mode - ${keyComplement}`}
          </Button>
        </Grid>
        {editMode && (
          <Grid item xs>
            <Button variant="contained" onClick={saveButton}>
              Save changes
            </Button>
          </Grid>
        )}
      </Grid>
      <Box sx={tableStyles}>
        <Box component="table" sx={{ overflowX: "auto" }} tabIndex={0}>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <Box component="th">ID</Box>
              <Box component="th">School Name</Box>
              {whichCourse.bundles.map((thisBundle) => {
                return (
                  <Box component="th" key={`th-${thisBundle.id}-${keyComplement}`}>
                    {thisBundle.name}
                  </Box>
                );
              })}
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {whichCourse.schools.map((thisSchool, currentIndex) => {
              return (
                <tr key={`td-${thisSchool.id}-${keyComplement}`}>
                  <Box component="td">{thisSchool.id}</Box>
                  <Box component="td">{thisSchool.name}</Box>
                  {whichCourse.bundles.map((thisBundle) => {
                    const isEnabled = thisSchool.licensedproducts.includes(thisBundle.id);
                    return (
                      <Box component="td" key={`td-${thisBundle.id}-${keyComplement}`}>
                        {editMode ? (
                          <Checkbox
                            size="small"
                            checked={isEnabled}
                            sx={{
                              color: "#000000",
                              "&.Mui-checked": {
                                color: "#3F51B5",
                              },
                            }}
                            onChange={() =>
                              setModifiedValues((currentValue) => {
                                if (isEnabled) {
                                  currentValue.schools[currentIndex].licensedproducts = currentValue.schools[currentIndex].licensedproducts.filter((value) => value !== thisBundle.id);
                                } else {
                                  currentValue.schools[currentIndex].licensedproducts.push(thisBundle.id);
                                }
                                return { ...currentValue };
                              })
                            }
                          />
                        ) : (
                          isEnabled && <CheckIcon sx={{ verticalAlign: "middle" }} />
                        )}
                      </Box>
                    );
                  })}
                </tr>
              );
            })}
          </tbody>
        </Box>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

I created a very simple repo with this code and a CloudFlare Pages deploy

- GitHub repo: https://github.com/LuisEnMarroquin/table-toggles-discard
- Live preview: https://toggle.pages.dev/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem with your code is this:

```
const [originalValues, setOriginalValues] = useState({ ...propsData });
const [modifiedValues, setModifiedValues] = useState({ ...propsData });
```

You just spread same object in two different states, by spread you shallowly copied only top level of object, but all other nested things are shared between `originalvalues` and `modifiedvalues` since those nested references were not copied.

And like that each time you check unchecked checkbox, like this:

```
else {                         
       currentValue.schools[currentIndex].licensedproducts.push(thisBundle.id);
     }
```

You are basically modifying both original and modified values, since you just pushed in that same `licencesedproducts` array that was shared because you were not copied deeply when setting initial state.
You should either do deep copy on initial state set(which I suggest), or/and in this part where you modify state to use spread of array in order to create new one, eg: `currentValue.schools[currentIndex].licensedproducts = [...currentValue.schools[currentIndex].licensedproducts, thisBundle.id]`

Comment: Thank you, I used `lodash/cloneDeep` and also implemented the second suggestion of not using `array.push`

Answer (score 1):

```
  const [originalValues, setOriginalValues] = useState({...propsData });
  const [modifiedValues, setModifiedValues] = useState({ ...propsData });

  currentValue.schools[currentIndex].licensedproducts = currentValue.schools[currentIndex].licensedproducts.filter((value) => value !== thisBundle.id);
  currentValue.schools[currentIndex].licensedproducts.push(thisBundle.id);
```

The issue was that you were using the same object to initialize both the states though you are spreading the object but that object also have inner objects. So those inner objects `bundles` and `schools` in both the states point to a single object in memory.
And in the onChange handler you are mutating the object as a result it updates both the state values.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to apply another logic to set `isEnabled`. I do not know
your business logic, however the most simple solution will be to use `!` operator:

```
const isEnabled = !thisSchool.licensedproducts.includes(thisBundle.id);
```